# how to mock a property with private setter using NSubstitute

Tags: c#, private, nsubstitute

I am having a class "Example" with a property "data" which has a private setter and I would like to mock that data property

```
Public class Example { public string data {get; private set;}}
```

I would like to mock the data property using NSubstitute. Could someone help me how to do it.

Comment: Likely not possible - most mocking libraries are not able to mock non-virtual, non-interface methods. Short of redesigning your classes you'll need some much heavier tool that can rewrite code like [Microsoft Moles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798308.aspx).

Comment: It might be worth noting whether you are able to edit the `Example` class. As noted by @AlexeiLevenkov, if you can't then NSub can't help you. If you can, @JohnKoerner's answer shows one way to do it.

Comment: Place the getter procedure in a `virtual` method and then mock that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

NSubstitute can only mock `abstract` or `virtual` methods on concrete classes.  If you can modify the underlying code to use an interface , then you could mock the interface:

```
public class Example : IExample { public string data { get; private set; } }
public interface IExample { string data { get; } }

[TestMethod]
public void One()
{
    var fakeExample = NSubstitute.Substitute.For<IExample>();
    fakeExample.data.Returns("FooBar");

    Assert.AreEqual("FooBar", fakeExample.data);
}
```

Comment: Making `Example.data` virtual would also work for this test without adding the interface. (Although I generally prefer interfaces for dynamic proxy-based mocking.)

Comment: Sounds correct, but I've been able to use substitute.Received(1).Method() where Method is not abstract or virtual.